# Square waves (Hall-effect sensor)

Tags: sensor, frequency, wave, square

I'm replacing the gearbox of my truck.
Both gearboxes (the old one and the new one) have speed sensors in the output shaft, but they don´t produce the same signals.

In order to make the new sensor compatible with the rest of the electronics of this truck, I have to "translate" the new signal so the engine computer sees what it wants to see.

The old sensor produces the following signals for each pin (labeled #3 and #4):

[image]

[image]

The new sensor produces these signals:

[image]

[image]

Basically, what I have to do is to make a circuit to vary the frequency (pin 3) and also invert the signal (pin 4).

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Hmm. Can you measure the frequency of sensor 2 at 0 kmph? You really think it is going to have a 4 Hz signal when stopped? I think it would be easier to use a different sensor than to try to generate a different frequency the way you are saying.

Comment: I'd be looking for a way to fit the old sensor into the new gearbox.